# Testing table, jasmine, angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a table with items

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="project in projects  | filter:query">
    <td><a href="#/{{project.prj_number}}">{{project.prj_number}}</a></td>
    <td>{{project.prj_title}}</td>
    <td>{{project.prj_manager}}</td>
    <td>{{project.prj_manager}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Trying to write a test for this with Jasmine. According to offical angular tutorial it would be like this if it was a list:

```
expect(repeater('.projects li').count()).toBe(2);
```

And that is working. But how do I do the same test if it's a table instead?

Tried this but it didn't work:

```
expect(repeater('.projects tr').count()).toBe(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(repeater('tbody tr').count()).toBe(2);
```

Other option is to change `<tbody>` to `<tbody class="projects">`

Comment: How do I test the same in Angular 2?

Comment: Yes Can you provide us with the solution in angular 2 as well